# Java mcrypt_create_iv

Tags: java, php, encryption

Is there an equivalent mcrypt_create_iv function for Java?

I'm creating a forum, I need users to be able to signup not only on the website but also within a client; I would like both registering methods to use the same encryption if possible.

Comment: Ha, I read your question completely backwards. Joke's on me, deleted my answer. In Java you're probably just going to have to generate X random bytes since I doubt there's a built-in helper for such a menial task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single call to create a random IV, and if you leave the IV out then the Oracle implementation will default to a zero IV (an IV consisting of N bytes set to `00` value, where N is the block size). Also note that in Java the `getBlockSize()` method returns the amount of bytes, not bits.

```java
Cipher enCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// create IV array of the correct size
final byte[] ivData = new byte[enCipher.getBlockSize()];
// create (or retrieve) a cryptographic secure random implementation (auto-seeded)
final SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
// fill the IV array with random data
rng.nextBytes(ivData);
// generate the ParameterSpec (to create a general parameter for Cipher.init())
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivData);
// and initialize with the new IV
enCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
```