# ColdFusion or Java equivalent to PHP encryption/decryption

Tags: java, php, algorithm, encryption, coldfusion

I have an API spec that reads:

**Encryption Algorithm**

The API utilizes the AES-128 (also known as Rijndael-128) algorithm with a 192-bit key in 
CBC mode for encryption and decryption of sensitive pieces of information – the password parameter in the user/signin and user/signup methods, the authentication token, etc. The steps of the algorithm are listed below:

**Encryption**

- Pad the input data so that its size is a multiple of the encryption algorithm block size – 16 bytes. In case the length of input data is a multiple of 16, a block of additional 16 bytes needs to be appended. The value of each pad byte is the number of pad bytes as an 'unsigned char'. That is, the last byte of the padded data should always be between 0x01 and 0x10.
- Generate a 16-byte long initialization vector (IV) for the encryption algorithm.
- Encrypt the padded data using AES-128 with the EK and the generated IV.
- Combine the IV with the encrypted data.
- Encode the result with urlsafe Base64. The urlsafe Base46 alphabet uses '–' instead of '+' and '_' instead of '/'.

**Decryption**

- Base64-decode the input data.
- Extract the first 16 bytes – these are the IV for the AES algorithm.
- Decrypt the data using AES-128 with the EK and IV.
- Read the value of the last byte of the decrypted data and remove that many bytes off its tail.

---

The only example provided by the supplier of this API is in PHP, using mcrypt.  I know absolutely nothing about PHP, and am not an encryption expert.  I need to be able to represent the above algorithm using ColdFusion 10.

I started by trying to take the example PHP files and find equivalents in either the ColdFusion tag or function library, and then by looking for a Java library with the same interface.  I just don't know enough to make this happen.

Is there someone here that can point me in the right direction, or work with me offline to assist?

EDIT:

Here's the example given, for the basic task of doing a "check" on the keys (partner key and encryption key) provided to me for use with the API.

Object Client.php, has this constructor:

```
public function __construct($hostApiUrl, $partnerKey, $encryptionKey, $token = null)
{
    $this->_pk = $partnerKey;
    $this->_ek = $encryptionKey;
    $this->_crypt = new Crypt($encryptionKey);
    $this->_url = rtrim($hostApiUrl, '/') . self::BASE_URL;
    if ($token) {
        $this->setUserSession($token);
    }
}
```

and this is the function I'm attempting to use:

```
public function checkKeys()
{
    $secret = $this->_encodeParam($this->_ek);
    $result = $this->call('partner/checkkeys', array(
        'secret' => $secret
    ));
    if (!$result || !$this->_isCodeOk($result->code)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So the client object already has the partner key and encryption key when this method is called, obviously.

so the "secret" is created by "encoding" the encryption key provided, using _encodeParam() method.  that looks like this:

```
protected function _encodeParam($secret)
{
    $secret = "{$secret}:{$this->_pk}";
    return $this->_crypt->encrypt($secret);
}
```

so the secret is appended with the partner key.  and then encrypted using this method in the crypt object (AES_BLOCK_SIZE is set as 16):

```
public function encrypt($data)
{
    $pad = self::AES_BLOCK_SIZE - strlen($data) % self::AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'win') !== false) {
        $random_source = MCRYPT_RAND;
    } else {
        $random_source = MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM;
    }
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(self::AES_BLOCK_SIZE, $random_source);
    mcrypt_generic_init($this->_td, $this->_key, $iv);
    $data = $iv . mcrypt_generic($this->_td, $data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->_td);

    return self::urlsafe_b64encode($data);
}
```

this is returned back to the above checkKeys() function which sends the request to the API, which then returns a response.  That actual API call is a POST which is easy enough to generate of course, but all those encryption hoops, including the MCRYPT library calls, are where I get stuck trying to determine the equivalent in CF10 or Java.

If I were to get an example thus far, I think I'd stand a chance of replicating the other functions in the crypt object (the ones that are even necessary, which may not be, since some may be built right into the CF encrypt() and decrypt() functions). This seems like a reasonable starting point, however.

Comment: The padding described is PKCS5/PKCS7 padding.  One or the other will be available.  In Java you need `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`.  You can help us help you by specifying what parts of the task you are having difficulty with.

Comment: +1 to rossum's comments. *RE: In Java you need `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`* .. and since CF runs on java, you can use it with the built in `encrypt\decrypt()` functions. Do a search on [coldfusion + encryption + aes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+[encryption]+AES) for examples. They will probably need tweaking, but should provide a good starting point. Important note: **To use keys larger than 128bits, you need install the [(JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)**.

Comment: The key size is only 128bits, so things are okay there it seems.  beyond that, i guess i'd need to post the first example they provide (checkKeys()) which contacts the api and verifies the encryption key and the partner key they provided.  I think once I have that simple task working, I would be able to start trying to build out the other functions from there.

Comment: A complete example would help. Obviously do not post your *real* key, only sample values.

Comment: okay, i'll add it to the example shortly.

Comment: added to original post... hope it's okay, i'm still getting used to how stackoverflow works.  ;)

Comment: Did they give you literal values to match, like a dummy key,iv and encrypted string, so you can tell when you have the correct result? Start simply with encrypting, using CF's encrypt function: [`encrypt(plainString, keyInBase64,"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "base64", ivByteArray)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html). A) As rossi said, PCKCS7 already takes care of the string for you B) You have the `key`. Just make sure it is in base64 format. too. C) The algorithm and encoding params are self-explanatory (cont'd)

Comment: D) You just need to generate an `iv`. AFAIK, CF does not have a function for that, but you can [do it with java using createObject(..)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264678/java-mcrypt-create-iv). All you should need is lines #1-#3.

Comment: @Leigh there are no dummy values to match, just the call to the checkKeys() API method that (i guess) would tell me whether I've done the encryption stuff right and have a value EK/PK pair.  I will check out how to create my own IV and see if I can post some proper CF code .

Comment: i'm not sure how to create a CF equivalent to that post on creating an IV.  Is it just something like CreateObject("Java", "Cipher") ?

Comment: WOuld this function in CF10 create an IV? 
generateSecretKey("AES")

Comment: *there are no dummy values to match, just the call to the checkKeys()* Too bad. Occasionally API's are smart enough to include a complete example, to help people avoid common mistakes like wrong encoding {shrug}. [This thread](http://blog.mxunit.org/2009/06/look-ma-no-password-secure-hashing-in.html) has a CF example. See `genSalt()` function. Just skip the toBase64() conversion.

Comment: No, [key and iv are different things](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html). `GenerateSecretKey()` is used to generate a *new* key. You already have an encryption key.

Comment: I'm pretty darn lost.  This is what I have so far:    

<cfset objCipher = CreateObject("java","javax.crypto.Cipher")>

<cfset objEncryptor  = objCipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")>

<cfset ivData = "1234567890123456">

<cfset secret = "#ek#:#pk#">

<cfset toSend = Encrypt(secret,ek,"AES","Base64","#ivData#")>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51625/discussion-between-leigh-and-user3266288)